# Is PPPoE suboptimal in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, gigabit-ethernet, pppoe

I've had a conversation with a technician from my ISP, where I complained that my 1 Gbps connection only goes up to 500-600 Mbps at most. I was told that the limitation is in Windows 10, specifically a suboptimal implementation of the PPPoE protocol, and instead I should connect via a Gigabit router.

I am skeptical of this explanation, so I would like to know how much truth there is in this claim. I haven't yet tested with a Gigabit router, I was only able to test so far with a direct connection from my Windows 10 laptop to the ISP-provided modem via a Cat6 UTP cable.

Comment: The technician was giving you a bunch of baloney. There is absolutely no truth in their statement

Comment: Did you reduce the MTU yet?

Comment: @Ramhound: Why do you think it is not a possibility?

Comment: @user1686 - Because the PPPoE connection is being made on the ISP provided modem not the device connected to the router.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't see where OP has said that this is the case?

Comment: The connection appears in Windows as WAN Miniport (PPPoE). @DanielB can you elaborate please on what you mean about the MTU?

Comment: PPPoE adds some overhead, so you may get issues with packet fragmentation which can severely affect performance. I never used PPPoE directly from Windows, so I cannot tell you what to change, but hopefully Google will turn up something.

Comment: @Ramhound i finally did a test today through a gigabit router, and to my surprise the speed test achieved 800-900 Mbps, as opposed to 500 on direct connection to the laptop. What could explain this difference? I had also changed the MTU value in Windows as suggested by Daniel B.